# How to design 3D items on ListView

Tags: android, listview

I want to design my ListView items in 3D shape, like on Google Inbox app, and material design.

How to can I design it with 3D and material design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use RecyclerView with CardView for material design ..

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html